# Running x86-64 executable on a x86_64 system cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: debian

I'm developing a C++ application in Visual Studio, compiled with WSL with G++ on an x64 system

Sorry if this is obvious, but I'm new to developing apps for Linux

/proc/cpuinfo flags:

```
fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 arat pku ospke md_clea
```

This is what I get when I run the executable with "./program.out":

```
bash: ./program.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

And with "sudo ./program.out":

```
./program.out: 1: ./program.out: 1: not found
./program.out: 1: ./program.out: ELF: not found
./program.out: 1: ./program.out: A��878G8G����DD: not found
./program.out: 1: ./program.out: A: not found
./program.out: 1: ./program.out: 1: not found
: No such filents.out: 1: ./BeXCoolAccounts.out: cannot open
./program.out: 2: ./program.out: @!l: not found
: No such filents.out: 1: ./BeXCoolAccounts.out: cannot open �GJ�V�JA
./program.out: 1: ./program.out: %@@@����nnppp-[-[����X�XA1A: not found
./program.out: 2: ./program.out: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

And "file ./program.out":

```
./program.out: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), no program header, missing section headers
```

When I was looking for a solution I tried "ldd ./program.out":

```
not a dynamic executable
```

And "strace ./program.out":

```
execve("./program.out", ["./program.out"], 0x7ffcc5b8b100 /* 27 vars */) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
strace: exec: Exec format error
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I've also used chmod a+x on the executable, but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no program header, missing section headers

> not a dynamic executable

I've no idea how you compiled it but the resulting file is very likely **not** a valid Linux executable. This might have happened for instance if you copied it via FTP using text mode. Or you edited the resulting file in a text editor.

This what `file` returns for a valid executable on Fedora 33:

```
file `which file`
/bin/file: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b8d5ba190593ec9e03e602d75dc0ea24a27a5cdb, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

Or on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ file `which file`
/usr/bin/file: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=2b26928f841d92afa31613c2c916a3abc96bbed8, stripped
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was that the file somehow got uploaded as ASCII, even though I had Binary mode enabled. Thanks :)